# Change java applet to java application

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet that runs a GUI. I want to call this GUI from my other program. I know that I need to turn this applet into an application.  I have an init() and a actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae). How can I do it?

My code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class survey extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    private TextField question;
    private Button enter, start;
    int count = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    String text, input;

    private Label intro1, intro2, intro3;
    private Label qone1, qone2, qone3, qone4, qone5, qone6, qone7, qone8, qone9, qone10, qone11, qone12;
    private Label qtwo1, qtwo2, qtwo3, qtwo4, qtwo5, qtwo6, qtwo7, qtwo8, qtwo9, qtwo10, qtwo11, qtwo12;
    private Label qthree1, qthree2, qthree3, qthree4, qthree5, qthree6, qthree7, qthree8, qthree9, qthree10, qthree11, qthree12;
    private Label qfour1, qfour2, qfour3, qfour4, qfour5, qfour6, qfour7, qfour8, qfour9, qfour10, qfour11, qfour12;
    private Label qfive1, qfive2, qfive3, qfive4, qfive5, qfive6, qfive7, qfive8, qfive9, qfive10, qfive11, qfive12;
    private Label qsix1, qsix2, qsix3, qsix4, qsix5, qsix6, qsix7, qsix8, qsix9, qsix10, qsix11, qsix12;
    private Label qseven1, qseven2, qseven3, qseven4, qseven5, qseven6, qseven7, qseven8, qseven9, qseven10, qseven11, qseven12;
    private Label qeight1, qeight2, qeight3, qeight4, qeight5, qeight6, qeight7, qeight8, qeight9, qeight10, qeight11, qeight12;
    private Label qnine1, qnine2, qnine3, qnine4, qnine5, qnine6, qnine7, qnine8, qnine9, qnine10, qnine11, qnine12;
    private Label qten1, qten2, qten3, qten4, qten5, qten6, qten7, qten8, qten9, qten10, qten11, qten12;
    private Label qeleven1, qeleven2, qeleven3, qeleven4, qeleven5, qeleven6,
    private Label finish1, finish2, finish3;


    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        start = new Button ("Start");
        question = new TextField(10);
        enter = new Button ("Enter");
        if (count == 0)
        {
            setBackground( Color.yellow);
            intro1 = new Label("Target Advertising", Label.CENTER);
            intro1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            intro2 = new Label("Welcome to this questionnaire. First, we would like to know more about your personal preferences.");
            intro3 = new Label("For each question, Input a rating between 0-9 (zero = least interested, 9 = most interested) in the text box. Click enter for next question.");

            add(intro1);
            add(intro2);
            add(intro3);
            intro1.setBounds(0,0,800,20);
            intro2.setBounds(15,20,800,20);
            intro3.setBounds(15,40,800,20);
            add(start);
            start.setBounds(370,60,70,23);
            start.addActionListener(this);
        }
        if(count == 1)
        {
            setBackground( Color.yellow );
            qone1 = new Label("Question 1", Label.LEFT);
            qone1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            qone2 = new Label("How much do you like action movies?");
            qone3 = new Label("0");
            qone4 = new Label("1");
            qone5 = new Label("2");
            qone6 = new Label("3");
            qone7 = new Label("4");
            qone8 = new Label("5");
            qone9 = new Label("6");
            qone10 = new Label("7");
            qone11 = new Label("8");
            qone12 = new Label("9");


            add(qone1);
            add(qone2);
            add(qone3);
            add(qone4);
            add(qone5);
            add(qone6);
            add(qone7);
            add(qone8);
            add(qone9);
            add(qone10);
            add(qone11);
            add(qone12);


            qone1.setBounds(15,0,800,20);
            qone2.setBounds(15,20,800,15);
            qone3.setBounds(15,60,800,15);
            qone4.setBounds(15,80,800,15);
            qone5.setBounds(15,100,800,15);
            qone6.setBounds(15,120,800,15);
            qone7.setBounds(15,140,800,15);
            qone8.setBounds(15,160,800,15);
            qone9.setBounds(15,180,800,15);
            qone10.setBounds(15,200,800,15);
            qone11.setBounds(15,220,800,15);
            qone12.setBounds(15,240,800,15);


            add(question);
            add(enter);
            question.setBounds(15,260,70,15);
            enter.setBounds(90,260,110,23);
            question.addActionListener(this);
            enter.addActionListener(this);
        }
        if (count == 2)
        {

            qtwo1 = new Label("Question 2", Label.LEFT);
            qtwo1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            qtwo2 = new Label("How much do you like Science Fiction?");
            qtwo3 = new Label("0");
            qtwo4 = new Label("1");
            qtwo5 = new Label("2");
            qtwo6 = new Label("3");
            qtwo7 = new Label("4");
            qtwo8 = new Label("5");
            qtwo9 = new Label("6");
            qtwo10 = new Label("7");
            qtwo11 = new Label("8");
            qtwo12 = new Label("9");


            add(qtwo1);
            add(qtwo2);
            add(qtwo3);
            add(qtwo4);
            add(qtwo5);
            add(qtwo6);
            add(qtwo7);
            add(qtwo8);
            add(qtwo9);
            add(qtwo10);
            add(qtwo11);
            add(qtwo12);


            qtwo1.setBounds(15,0,800,20);
            qtwo2.setBounds(15,20,800,15);
            qtwo3.setBounds(15,60,800,15);
            qtwo4.setBounds(15,80,800,15);
            qtwo5.setBounds(15,100,800,15);
            qtwo6.setBounds(15,120,800,15);
            qtwo7.setBounds(15,140,800,15);
            qtwo8.setBounds(15,160,800,15);
            qtwo9.setBounds(15,180,800,15);
            qtwo10.setBounds(15,200,800,15);
            qtwo11.setBounds(15,220,800,15);
            qtwo12.setBounds(15,240,800,15);


            add(question);
            add(enter);
            question.setBounds(15,260,70,15);
            enter.setBounds(90,260,110,23);
            question.addActionListener(this);
            enter.addActionListener(this);
        }
        if(count == 3)
        {

            qthree1 = new Label("Question 3", Label.LEFT);
            qthree1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            qthree2 = new Label("How much do you like comedy?");
            qthree3 = new Label("0");
            qthree4 = new Label("1");
            qthree5 = new Label("2");
            qthree6 = new Label("3");
            qthree7 = new Label("4");
            qthree8 = new Label("5");
            qthree9 = new Label("6");
            qthree10 = new Label("7");
            qthree11 = new Label("8");
            qthree12 = new Label("9");


            add(qthree1);
            add(qthree2);
            add(qthree3);
            add(qthree4);
            add(qthree5);
            add(qthree6);
            add(qthree7);
            add(qthree8);
            add(qthree9);
            add(qthree10);
            add(qthree11);
            add(qthree12);


            qthree1.setBounds(15,0,800,20);
            qthree2.setBounds(15,20,800,15);
            qthree3.setBounds(15,60,800,15);
            qthree4.setBounds(15,80,800,15);
            qthree5.setBounds(15,100,800,15);
            qthree6.setBounds(15,120,800,15);
            qthree7.setBounds(15,140,800,15);
            qthree8.setBounds(15,160,800,15);
            qthree9.setBounds(15,180,800,15);
            qthree10.setBounds(15,200,800,15);
            qthree11.setBounds(15,220,800,15);
            qthree12.setBounds(15,240,800,15);


            add(question);
            add(enter);
            question.setBounds(15,260,70,15);
            enter.setBounds(90,260,110,23);
            question.addActionListener(this);
            enter.addActionListener(this);
        }
        if(count == 4)
        {


            qfour1 = new Label("Question 4", Label.LEFT);
            qfour1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            qfour2 = new Label("How much do you like luxary cars?");
            qfour3 = new Label("0");
            qfour4 = new Label("1");
            qfour5 = new Label("2");
            qfour6 = new Label("3");
            qfour7 = new Label("4");
            qfour8 = new Label("5");
            qfour9 = new Label("6");
            qfour10 = new Label("7");
            qfour11 = new Label("8");
            qfour12 = new Label("9");


            add(qfour1);
            add(qfour2);
            add(qfour3);
            add(qfour4);
            add(qfour5);
            add(qfour6);
            add(qfour7);
            add(qfour8);
            add(qfour9);
            add(qfour10);
            add(qfour11);
            add(qfour12);


            qfour1.setBounds(15,0,800,20);
            qfour2.setBounds(15,20,800,15);
            qfour3.setBounds(15,60,800,15);
            qfour4.setBounds(15,80,800,15);
            qfour5.setBounds(15,100,800,15);
            qfour6.setBounds(15,120,800,15);
            qfour7.setBounds(15,140,800,15);
            qfour8.setBounds(15,160,800,15);
            qfour9.setBounds(15,180,800,15);
            qfour10.setBounds(15,200,800,15);
            qfour11.setBounds(15,220,800,15);
            qfour12.setBounds(15,240,800,15);


            add(question);
            add(enter);
            question.setBounds(15,260,70,15);
            enter.setBounds(90,260,110,23);

            question.addActionListener(this);
            enter.addActionListener(this);
        }
        if(count == 5)
        {


            qfive1 = new Label("Question 5", Label.LEFT);
            qfive1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            qfive2 = new Label("How much do you like trucks?");
            qfive3 = new Label("0");
            qfive4 = new Label("1");
            qfive5 = new Label("2");
            qfive6 = new Label("3");
            qfive7 = new Label("4");
            qfive8 = new Label("5");
            qfive9 = new Label("6");
            qfive10 = new Label("7");
            qfive11 = new Label("8");
            qfive12 = new Label("9");


            add(qfive1);
            add(qfive2);
            add(qfive3);
            add(qfive4);
            add(qfive5);
            add(qfive6);
            add(qfive7);
            add(qfive8);
            add(qfive9);
            add(qfive10);
            add(qfive11);
            add(qfive12);


            qfive1.setBounds(15,0,800,20);
            qfive2.setBounds(15,20,800,15);
            qfive3.setBounds(15,60,800,15);
            qfive4.setBounds(15,80,800,15);
            qfive5.setBounds(15,100,800,15);
            qfive6.setBounds(15,120,800,15);
            qfive7.setBounds(15,140,800,15);
            qfive8.setBounds(15,160,800,15);
            qfive9.setBounds(15,180,800,15);
            qfive10.setBounds(15,200,800,15);
            qfive11.setBounds(15,220,800,15);
            qfive12.setBounds(15,240,800,15);


            add(question);
            add(enter);
            question.setBounds(15,260,70,15);
            enter.setBounds(90,260,110,23);


            question.addActionListener(this);
            enter.addActionListener(this);
        }







        if(count == 7)
        {

            finish1 = new Label("Thank You." , Label.CENTER);
            finish1.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 50));
            finish2 = new Label("Questionnaire Completed.", Label.CENTER);
            finish2.setFont(new Font("Times-Roman", Font.BOLD, 50));

            add(finish1);
            add(finish2);

            finish1.setBounds(0,200,800,60);
            finish2.setBounds(0,300,800,60);
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String button = ae.getActionCommand();
        text = question.getText();
        b = 0;
        c = 0;






        if (count == 6)
        {
            input = text.toUpperCase();
            remove(enter);
            remove(question);
            question.setText("");
            remove(qsix1);
            remove(qsix2);
            remove(qsix3);
            remove(qsix4);
            remove(qsix5);
            remove(qsix6);
            remove(qsix7);
            remove(qsix8);
            remove(qsix9);
            remove(qsix10);
            remove(qsix11);
            remove(qsix12);

            try{
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("lets3.txt",true);
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                  out.write(new String(input));
                  out.write("\n");
                  out.close();
                  }

              catch (Exception e){
                      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
            if(input.equals("OL"))
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 7;
                init();
            }
            else
            {
                b = 2;
                count = 7;
                init();
            }

        }
        if (count == 5)
        {

            input = text.toUpperCase();
            remove(enter);
            remove(question);
            question.setText("");
            remove(qfive1);
            remove(qfive2);
            remove(qfive3);
            remove(qfive4);
            remove(qfive5);
            remove(qfive6);
            remove(qfive7);
            remove(qfive8);
            remove(qfive9);
            remove(qfive10);
            remove(qfive11);
            remove(qfive12);

            try{
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("lets3.txt",true);
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                  out.write(new String(input));
                  out.write("\n");
                  out.close();
                  }

              catch (Exception e){
                      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
            if(input.equals("BR"))
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 6;
                init();
            }
            else
            {
                b = 2;
                count = 6;
                init();
            }

        }
        if (count == 4)
        {
            input = text.toLowerCase();
            remove(enter);
            remove(question);
            question.setText("");
            remove(qfour1);
            remove(qfour2);
            remove(qfour3);
            remove(qfour4);
            remove(qfour5);
            remove(qfour6);
            remove(qfour7);
            remove(qfour8);
            remove(qfour9);
            remove(qfour10);
            remove(qfour11);
            remove(qfour12);

            try{
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("lets3.txt",true);
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                  out.write(new String(input));
                  out.write("\n");
                  out.close();
                  }

              catch (Exception e){
                      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
            if(input.equals("no"))
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 5;
                init();
            }
            else
            {
                b = 2;
                count = 5;
                init();
            }

        }
        if (count == 3)
        {
            input = text.toLowerCase();
            remove(enter);
            remove(question);
            question.setText("");
            remove(qthree1);
            remove(qthree2);
            remove(qthree3);
            remove(qthree4);
            remove(qthree5);
            remove(qthree6);
            remove(qthree7);
            remove(qthree8);
            remove(qthree9);
            remove(qthree10);
            remove(qthree11);
            remove(qthree12);

            try{
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("lets3.txt",true);
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                  out.write(new String(input));
                  out.write("\n");
                  out.close();
                  }

              catch (Exception e){
                      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
            if(input.equals("black"))
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 4;
                init();
            }
            else
            {
                b = 2;
                count = 4;
                init();
            }

        }
        if (count == 2)
        {
            input = text.toLowerCase();
            remove(enter);
            remove(question);
            question.setText("");
            remove(qtwo1);
            remove(qtwo2);
            remove(qtwo3);
            remove(qtwo4);
            remove(qtwo5);
            remove(qtwo6);
            remove(qtwo7);
            remove(qtwo8);
            remove(qtwo9);
            remove(qtwo10);
            remove(qtwo11);
            remove(qtwo12);

            try{
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("lets3.txt",true);
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                  out.write(new String(input));
                  out.write("\n");
                  out.close();
                  }

              catch (Exception e){
                      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
            if(input.equals("yes"))
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 3;
                init();
            }
            else
            {
                b = 2;
                count = 3;
                init();
            }
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            input = text.toUpperCase();
            remove(enter);
            remove(question);
            question.setText("");
            remove(qone1);
            remove(qone2);
            remove(qone3);
            remove(qone4);
            remove(qone5);
            remove(qone6);
            remove(qone7);
            remove(qone8);
            remove(qone9);
            remove(qone10);
            remove(qone11);
            remove(qone12);



            try{
              FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("lets3.txt",true);
              BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
              out.write(new String(input));
              out.write("\n");
              out.close();
              }

          catch (Exception e){
                  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
              }

            if(input.equals("i"))
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 2;
                init();
            }
            else 
            {
                b = 1;
                count = 2;
                init();
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            remove(intro1);
            remove(intro2);
            remove(intro3);
            remove(start);
            count = 1;
            init();
        }
        this.validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty, you need to re-write your program from scratch so that you can incorporate OOP techniques, arrays, collections, and other advantages that Java has to offer.  I recommend:

- First of all since your code displays a series of questions and prompts for response, don't hard-code the questions in the code but make them part of the data. Have your program read in a text file that holds the questions. This will allow you to change questions or add questions without altering code.
- Create a non-GUI Question class that holds questions and user responses and that is used by the GUI as its "model".
- Create an ArrayList of Question objects.
- For your GUI, code to the JPanel, not the applet or the JFrame. This will give you the option of using your GUI in a JFrame or a JApplet, or even a JDialog or embedded in another JPanel should you so desire.
- If you will need to swap display panels, consider using CardLayout for this purpose.
- If however all you'll be doing is changing the text of the question, then display the question text in a JLabel and when you want to change it, call setText(...) on the JLabel passing in the new question's text.
- Use the user-friendly layout managers to ease your work of laying out components in the GUI.
- Your current code has a lot of unnecessary redundencies. Use of arrays and collections such as ArrayLists will remove many of these redudancies and make debugging and upgrading **much** easier.
- As others have stated and as I stated in my earlier comment, you should move up to the Swing library as it is much more flexible and robust than the AWT gui library that you are currently using. The Swing tutorials will show you what you need to know to create beautiful Swing programs.

Comment: +1 for an honest, constructive assessment; well-written code will be easy to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a main() method, make a Frame for your applet, add the applet to the frame, and call the applet's init() and start() methods. See my Mandelbrot.java for an example: https://jcomeau.com/src/java/com/jcomeau/Mandelbrot.java

One advantage of this approach is that it can be used with any existing applet, to allow it to function as either an applet or application. Use a JFrame if you're using Swing components, otherwise it should work pretty nearly the same.

Comment: You have a program that may be useful as an applet, so this seems like the best approach, as you can learn to refactor, which is a very important lesson, and so refactor it to be an applet that works the same but the code is improved, by adding new methods, and perhaps classes.  By moving all the code that may be used in more than one application, move it to its own class, which will make it easier to have it work with both an application and applet.

Answer (score 1):

https://way2java.com/applets/applet-to-application/

Following are the changes to be made from Applet to Application

1. Delete the statement "import java.applet" package
2. Replace extends Applet with Frame
3. Replace the init() method with constructor
4. Check the layout (for Applet, the default layout is FlowLayout and for Frame, it is BorderLayout)
5. Add setXXX() methods like setSize() etc.
6. Add the main() method
7. HTML is not required (delete it)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll want to change all the non swing components to swing components. For events, they're roughly the same for both applets and swing applications. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you want it inside a window all you need to do is this:

```
    public Object[] startNewSurvey()
    {
        java.awt.Frame f = new java.awt.Frame("You're title here.");
        f.setSize(new Dimension(<Width>, <Height>));
        f.setResizable(false);

        survey s = new survey();
        s.init();
        f.add(s);

        f.setVisible(true);
        return new Object[] { f, s };
    }
```

That will just instance a brand new frame and put another new instance of your survey class in that frame, then display it. It also returns a 2 sized Object[] array containing the new Frame and survey instances made. Hope that helps.

Comment: I want cal call this applet in another application. So When I run the other application, this GUI will pop up and run concurrently.